# Why there is an attribute error while trying to display an image(PIL object)

Tags: python, jupyter-notebook, python-imaging-library

I faced some problems while trying to save images from the archive as pillow objects to the list. I am using pillow library for python and jupyter notebook to work with the images. And initially I wanted to have a list of vocabularies, where one of the keys would be a pillow object so I could easily get my image(it seems to me so, may be I am wrong). I open images in the archive one at a time as file object and then open it as pillow object. At this step I want to save this pillow object so I could work with it later. All the images are fine, if I use display while appending them to the list, they are displayed. But there is one thing which looks weird for me. If I don't display images while they are added to the list, I can't display them further if I fetch them from that list. I wish you could help me. I suppose the problem may be in my inexperience in working with files. May be there is a better way to do what I need.

```
import zipfile

from PIL import Image
import pytesseract
import cv2 as cv
import numpy as np

#%%
file = zipfile.ZipFile('small_img.zip', 'r')

data = []
images = []
for name in file.namelist():
    with file.open(name, 'r') as img_file:
        image = Image.open(img_file)
        data.append({'name': name, 'PilObject': image, 'text': None, 'bounding_boxes': None})
        images.append(image)
        #display(image)
        #if I leave the line above I could display my images further, fetching them from the list
        #If not, an error occurs
#%%
display(images[0])

    ---------------------------------------------------------------------------

AttributeError                            Traceback (most recent call last)

d:\pythonprojects\untitled\venv\lib\site-packages\IPython\core\formatters.py in __call__(self, obj)
    343             method = get_real_method(obj, self.print_method)
    344             if method is not None:
--> 345                 return method()
    346             return None
    347         else:

d:\pythonprojects\untitled\venv\lib\site-packages\PIL\Image.py in _repr_png_(self)
    670         """
    671         b = io.BytesIO()
--> 672         self.save(b, "PNG")
    673         return b.getvalue()
    674 

d:\pythonprojects\untitled\venv\lib\site-packages\PIL\Image.py in save(self, fp, format, **params)
   2122 
   2123         # may mutate self!
-> 2124         self._ensure_mutable()
   2125 
   2126         save_all = params.pop("save_all", False)

d:\pythonprojects\untitled\venv\lib\site-packages\PIL\Image.py in _ensure_mutable(self)
    616     def _ensure_mutable(self):
    617         if self.readonly:
--> 618             self._copy()
    619         else:
    620             self.load()

d:\pythonprojects\untitled\venv\lib\site-packages\PIL\Image.py in _copy(self)
    609 
    610     def _copy(self):
--> 611         self.load()
    612         self.im = self.im.copy()
    613         self.pyaccess = None

d:\pythonprojects\untitled\venv\lib\site-packages\PIL\ImageFile.py in load(self)
    241                         while True:
    242                             try:
--> 243                                 s = read(self.decodermaxblock)
    244                             except (IndexError, struct.error) as e:
    245                                 # truncated png/gif

d:\pythonprojects\untitled\venv\lib\site-packages\PIL\PngImagePlugin.py in load_read(self, read_bytes)
    861         self.__idat = self.__idat - read_bytes
    862 
--> 863         return self.fp.read(read_bytes)
    864 
    865     def load_end(self):

~\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python37\lib\zipfile.py in read(self, n)
    928         self._offset = 0
    929         while n > 0 and not self._eof:
--> 930             data = self._read1(n)
    931             if n < len(data):
    932                 self._readbuffer = data

~\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python37\lib\zipfile.py in _read1(self, n)
    996             data = self._decompressor.unconsumed_tail
    997             if n > len(data):
--> 998                 data += self._read2(n - len(data))
    999         else:
   1000             data = self._read2(n)

~\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python37\lib\zipfile.py in _read2(self, n)
   1028         n = min(n, self._compress_left)
   1029 
-> 1030         data = self._fileobj.read(n)
   1031         self._compress_left -= len(data)
   1032         if not data:

~\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python37\lib\zipfile.py in read(self, n)
    751                         "is an open writing handle on it. "
    752                         "Close the writing handle before trying to read.")
--> 753             self._file.seek(self._pos)
    754             data = self._file.read(n)
    755             self._pos = self._file.tell()

AttributeError: 'NoneType' object has no attribute 'seek'

<PIL.PngImagePlugin.PngImageFile image mode=RGB size=3600x6300 at 0x24E8704B1C8>
```

Comment: Call `image.load()` inside the loop - if you do absolutely nothing with the `Image` object, it never gets loaded, and after the loop it *cannot* be loaded, because the file is no longer open.

Comment: @jasonharper I tried that. That doesn't seem to be it. See the test source below, it works fine just with Image.open().

Answer (score 0):

So I'm curious, does the code in the question work as is?
Because there seem to be various strange things going on.
(I can't test it as is, for lack of the opencv package.)

As a baseline, used this to check that images do work,
when read from an archive.

```
import zipfile

from PIL import Image

archive = zipfile.ZipFile('media.zip', 'r')
fileNames = archive.namelist()
fileNames.pop(0)  # Remove directory entry (here, 'media/').

# Opening the image files, could be as simple as this:
images = [Image.open(fName) for fName in fileNames]

# Test images, by displaying them with tkinter.
import tkinter as tk
from PIL import ImageTk
tk.Tk()
# Store references, to keep PhotoImages alive (for tkinter).
tkImages = [ImageTk.PhotoImage(img) for img in images]
for img in tkImages: tk.Label(image=img).pack()
tk.mainloop()
```

Can you update the loop where you open the images,
according to this, and see if the problem persists?